# Create conversion methods between S4 classes from other packages

Tags: r, r-s4

Suppose I want to create an R package which defines coercion methods (`methods::as`) between S4 classes **which are defined in other packages**.

When I'm creating a package with its own S4 class, I can add conversions to and from other classes like this:

```r
setAs("MyClass", "OtherClass", function(from) myfun(from))
```

And these work fine once the package is loaded, provided that the classes are exported correctly.

But now suppose that I want to take class `A` from `packageA`, and class `B` from `packageB`, both of which are S4 classes, and I want to create my own conversion functions to/from `A`<->`B` (assuming that neither package defined a conversion function to/from the class of the other package).

If I try to add something like this:

```r
setAs("A", "B", function(from) castAtoB(from))
setAs("B", "A", function(from) castBtoA(from))
```

And then install and load the package, the methods won't be available - e.g. something like this:

```r
library(methods)
library(packageA)
library(packageB)
library(myPackage)

objA <- packageA::createObjA()
as(objA, "B")
```

Will fail with a message like:

```
Error in as(objA, "B") : 
  no method or default for coercing “A” to “B”
```

How can I register these methods so that they would be available when loading my package?

Comment: `function(from) myfun(from)` can be replaced by just `myfun` in the `setAs` call. Same for similar functions (`castAtoB` and vice-versa).

Comment: in your example, you haven't actually loaded your package. Was that intentional?

Comment: @JDL sorry, added it in the code, although it doesn't make a difference when I try to run some code like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself: getting this to work requires adding the following line in the `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
export()
```

Then it works correctly.